# Corda view consumed states in terminal

Tags: rpc, corda

is there an easy way to view the consumed states in the terminal with the CordaRPCOps interface? It seems that vaultQuery returns unconsumed states by default and I can't figure out how to use vaultQueryBy or anything with the criteria.

I know that there should be consumed states because I can see them with H2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you could always write a short API to expose the states:

there is a sample for /asset in corda existing samples:

here is a code snippet api for your scenario:

```
@GET
@Path("asset")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
fun getAssets(): List<StateAndRef<ContractState>> {
    val consumedCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED)
    return services.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>(consumedCriteria).states
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ricky says, you'll have to provide an API or write a client to speak to your CorDapp via RPC (e.g. https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V1/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/client/ExampleClientRPC.kt).

In theory, `run vaultQueryByCriteria contractStateType: com.example.state.IOUState, criteria: { Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED }` could work. However, in `vaultQueryByCriteria`, the `criteria` parameter is of type `QueryCriteria`, which is an abstract class. There is no way currently in the shell to specify which concrete subclass of `QueryCriteria` you wish to use.

I have raised an issue here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/2351.