# Is there any way to see consumed states in shell Terminal of a party?

Tags: corda

My cordApp does is that it create a Trade and update the Trade. To update, counterparty run update flow and take my original state as input making it consumed in the update transaction. 
So when i run vault query to see my states, it is only showing unconsumed states. How can i see both consumed and unconsumed states in shell.
Below is how i run vault query.

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.template.states.TradeState
```

But this only shows unconsumed states.

By shell i means the terminal node that is started after calling runnodes.bat file

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195934/corda-view-consumed-states-in-terminal) (you can see answer there).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Corda view consumed states in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195934/corda-view-consumed-states-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `CONSUMED` states you need to pass a QueryCriteria to the vaultQuery command. But the node's CRaSH shell doesn't currently support QueryCriteria.

As parameters are passed to a command using YAML syntax in the node shell and QueryCriteria is an abstract type, the concrete subclass of it cannot be created using YAML syntax.

The known limitations are documented here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#limitations

Answer (score 0):

The new Corda Node Explorer allows you to look at all different states. It is no longer just for CordaFinance cordapp. You have lot of filters. Select the various Contract States, UnConsumed or Unconsumed, Relevant or Not-Relevant, as well as Parties selection. Please note that you login with your Node's RPC credentials. This would show only Vault states information that are accessible by that node RPC user.

see link https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-explorer.html